# Finding headings for multiple lists in a single sheet and autofilling a formula from the bottom

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hopefully my title is clear. I am trying to first find the heading "WT/PC" in a list, going to the bottom of that list, copying the formula that is there all the way up until the header, and then find the next instance of "WT/PC" on the sheet (they aren't always in the same column) and then do the same for it. I want to do this about 10-20 times. I have a combination of Macro Recorder Code and some that I have added. I have located WT/Pc, went to the bottom of the list, but now am having syntactical issues with using Autofill to fill up the column using  xlUp

Sample picture to help better visualize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wwpf.jpg
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wwpf.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQdFx.png)
Current Code:

```
Sub Formula_Fill_Using_Find()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rowCount, row_ix, temp, i As Integer
Dim TD_COL_IX As Integer
Dim td_value As String
Dim td_values() As String

' #################
' Count rows starting in column A
' #################
 For row_ix = 1 To 25 ' 25 was previously "rowCount"

ActiveCell.Select
Cells.Find(What:="WT/PC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Selection.End(xlDown).Select

ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":" & 
Left(ActiveCell.Address, Len(ActiveCell.Address)) & xlUp)

Next row_ix



End Sub
```

Comment: Please use the standard uploader for pictures.

Comment: My issue is in my ActiveCell.Autofill line. Can't get the proper syntax to go from the currently selected cell (where the formula is located) and then up.

Comment: I can't use the standard uploader or I would Mat's Mug. Do you have any advice regarding my actual question instead of a critique on the format I am limited to using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReverseFill()
    Dim ur As Range, found As Range, adr As Variant, cr As Range, lr As Long

    Set ur = Sheet1.UsedRange
    Set found = ur.Find("WT/PC", , xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, , False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        adr = found.Address

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Do
            Set cr = found.CurrentRegion:          lr = cr.Rows.Count - 1
            cr.Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1).Formula = found.Offset(lr).Formula
            Set found = ur.FindNext(found)
        Loop While found.Address <> adr
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```